# Which of the following groups are isomorphic to each other?

Tags: group-theory

Which of the following groups are isomorphic? 
$$1:(\mathbb Q_{\ge 0}   ,\times , 1),  \quad 2:(\mathbb R   ,+ , 0),\quad 3:(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}   ,\times , 1) , \quad 4:(\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}   ,\times , 1)   .       $$

First of all, I decided that group 1 is isomorphic to none of the other groups purely because the cardinality of its set of elements is different then all of the others. This by definition means that no bijection exists between group 1 and any of the others. Secondly, group 4 is two dimensional, it needs two parameters to uniquely describe a point on it. Thus it is isomorphic to none of the other groups. Group 2 and 3 are easily shown to be isomorphic by the bijection $f:(\mathbb R   ,+ , 0) \to(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}   ,\times , 1)$ via $f(x)= e^x$.

I am pretty confident that 2 and 3 are isomorphic but I am wondering if the reasoning that 1 and 4 are isomorphic to none of the others is correct. If anyone could comment on this that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the first one can't be to the rest because isomorphisms are bijections, and they don't have the same cardinality.

$4$ isn't isomorphic to $2$ or $3$ because it has an element of order $4$(i), while the others don't.

$2$ isn't isomorphic to $3$ since $2$ has no elements of order two while $3$ does (-1).

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$ is indeed countable; $(\mathbb{R}^*, \times)$ has a subgroup of order two, $(\mathbb{C}^*, \times)$ is divisible.

**NB:** $\exp : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^*$ is not onto!

Answer (score 0):

Your argument for $4$ does not convince me. You can look at the torsion to see that the group $4$ is not isomorphic to the others.

The "isomorphism" you describe between $2$ and $3$ is not surjective. In fact you can also distinguish these two groups using the torsion.